# Using background image in the embedded web browser control

Tags: vb.net, background-image, webbrowser-control

I am working on a project which will allow non-html efficient users to develop html templates within our windows forms application.

I have got the code to spit out the html for what I want, and it works perfectly in Chrome, but not in the embedded web browser

Here is my generated html code:

```
<body style="background-color:#f5f5f5;">
<div style="height:148.00mm; width:210.00mm; min-height:148.00mm; min-width:210.00mm; background-image:url('file:///C:/Images/Items/9_1_WP_000088.jpg'); background-size:cover;">
</div>
</body>
```

I am using the web browser control to allow the user to preview what they are doing prior to packaging up into a HTML document for use.

Please can someone give me some pointers on getting the background image working in the embedded browser/ie?

Comment: IE runs the browser control in document mode 7 by default, so maybe that could be the issue.  Try including the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` to instruct IE to use the latest document mode it has available.

Comment: I have tried opening the HTML in ie from a text file and the image does not display so I don't think it's the document mode that's the issue